# Does the gate in Mor Ardain's capital ever open?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

To the west of Kedeigh Gate in Alba Cavanich, Empire of Mor Ardain, there is a large gate blocking the path. Behind it are NPCs that say the following:

> Person 1: This door is not door that open?
>
> Person 2: Yeah, you don't see it open very often...

The boxes stacked next to the door look like they might let you jump over the gate, but they are too high to jump up to. I know you can get behind the door by detouring through Nharil Central Plaza, but is there a way to open the door for a more direct path?

[image: closed gate in Mor Ardain]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having completed the main story, the answer appears to be no, the gate in Mor Ardain's capital does not open.